# Instanced Quads using SSBO centres

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am creating a GPU particle system. I use a compute shader to advect particles which are stored in an SSBO as:

```
// Storing x y and z although only looking at 2D for now
float pos[3 * NUM_PARTICLES]    // { x1, y1, z1, ... xn, yn, zn }
```

I also have a VBO containing base `x,y` for the four vertices of a quad as

```
float vert[4 * 4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
```

i.e. the quad fills the viewport as my MVP maps [0 1] to the full viewport.

I would like to use `glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, NUM_PARTICLES)` but rather than using per instance data stored in VBOs and setting them using `glVertexAttribDivisor` as I want to use the data in the SSBO directly for each instance. My initial thoughts were to modify the vertex shader like this:

```
#version 430 core

// Inputs of the quad (triangle strip) to render
uniform mat4 mvp;
in vec2 inPos;

// Position of particles and hence quad centres
layout(binding = 7) buffer particlePosBlock
{
    float pos[ ];
};

void main()
{
    // Get quad centre for this instance as a vec2
    vec2 quadcentre = vec2(pos[0 + gl_InstanceID * 3], pos[0 + gl_InstanceID * 3]);

    // Scale and shift the vertex positions from the base quad data
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(inPos, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

But how do I modify the `gl_Position` values to scale and shift an instance based on the SSBO data? I assume some kind of matrix transform? Also, will indexing into the SSBO like this kill performance?